# How do i set a value and get a value/variable in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

im kind of new to coding,

Here is my code and the error im having

```
supplier_105 = {
    "city": "Port Bradley",
    "contact_firstname": "Brittany",
    "contact_lastname": "Costa",
    "contact_title": "Mrs",
    "country": "Australia",
    "email": "brittany8706.costa@gmail.com",
    "notes": "",
    "phone": "(08) 6939 8022",
    "postcode": "3880",
    "state": "Costa",
    "street_address": "6/81 Heather Rosebowl",
    "supplier_id": 105,
    "supplier_name": "Rodriguez, Carter and Johnson"
}

# Write your code here
# 1. Define the class here
class Supplier:
   
      def __init__(self, city, contact_firstname,contact_lastname,contact_title,country,email,notes,phone,postcode,state,street_address,supplier_id,supplier_name):
        print("Initialiser called")
        self.city = city
        self.contact_firstname = contact_firstname
        self.contact_lastname = contact_lastname 
        self.contact_title = contact_title
        self.country = country
        self.email = email
        self.notes= notes
        self.phone = phone
        self.postcode = postcode
        self.state = state
        self.street_address = street_address
        self.supplier_id = supplier_id
        self.supplier_name = supplier_name
        

def get_state(self):
    return "The state is {} and the postcode is {}".format(self.state, self.postcode)

print(Supplier_105.supplier_name)

# 2. Instantiate the class
Supplier_105 = Supplier("Port Bradley","Brittany","Costa","Mrs","Australia","brittany8706.costa@gmail.com","","(08) 6939 8022","3880","Costa","6/81 Heather Rosebowl","105","Rodriguez, Carter and Johnson")

# 3. Call its methods here
print(Supplier_105.get_state())
```

**ERROR**

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-70798f9ef411> in <module>
     39         return "{} is {} years old".format(self.state, self.postcode)
     40 
---> 41 print(Supplier_105.supplier_name)
     42 
     43 # 2. Instantiate the class

NameError: name 'Supplier_105' is not defined
```

I'm trying to get the state and postcode formatted as "state and postcode" using the method/function, but it is not working. I am also trying to to set the postcode in the instance variable to the value of the parameter passed.

Any help on this would greatly be appreciated <3

Comment: You're getting that error because you're trying to print an attribute of `Supplier_105` before you actually define `Supplier_105`. Instantiate the class before trying to print anything from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of mistakes

- The object of the class was defined after usage
- The method `get_state(state)` was indented wrong

```py
supplier_105 = {
    "city": "Port Bradley",
    "contact_firstname": "Brittany",
    "contact_lastname": "Costa",
    "contact_title": "Mrs",
    "country": "Australia",
    "email": "brittany8706.costa@gmail.com",
    "notes": "",
    "phone": "(08) 6939 8022",
    "postcode": "3880",
    "state": "Costa",
    "street_address": "6/81 Heather Rosebowl",
    "supplier_id": 105,
    "supplier_name": "Rodriguez, Carter and Johnson",
}


# Write your code here
# 1. Define the class here
class Supplier:
    def __init__(
        self,
        city,
        contact_firstname,
        contact_lastname,
        contact_title,
        country,
        email,
        notes,
        phone,
        postcode,
        state,
        street_address,
        supplier_id,
        supplier_name,
    ):
        print("Initialiser called")
        self.city = city
        self.contact_firstname = contact_firstname
        self.contact_lastname = contact_lastname
        self.contact_title = contact_title
        self.country = country
        self.email = email
        self.notes = notes
        self.phone = phone
        self.postcode = postcode
        self.state = state
        self.street_address = street_address
        self.supplier_id = supplier_id
        self.supplier_name = supplier_name

    def get_state(self):
        return "The state is {} and the postcode is {}".format(self.state, self.postcode)


# 2. Instantiate the class
Supplier_105 = Supplier(
    "Port Bradley",
    "Brittany",
    "Costa",
    "Mrs",
    "Australia",
    "brittany8706.costa@gmail.com",
    "",
    "(08) 6939 8022",
    "3880",
    "Costa",
    "6/81 Heather Rosebowl",
    "105",
    "Rodriguez, Carter and Johnson",
)
print(Supplier_105.supplier_name)

# 3. Call its methods here
print(Supplier_105.get_state())
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello so if I understood correctly you would like to be able to access and change the variable stoe in your supplier_105 object. So here we go:

1. **Supplier_105 in your code is setup as a dictionary**. Dictionary work with the key/value system. They are not iterable since the object inside it doesn't have any index. **If you dont need to use the dictionnary you created at the top of your code skip step 1 and 2.**
2. **Too access your variable** inside a dictionnary you would have to check the correct key for the value you want to get. In you situation to access the value of city you would have to write: supplier_105["city"].
3. **There's a problem with your indentation** if you want to setup the get and set of your class Supplier they should be indented in a way were they are actually in the class like this:

> Blockquote

```
class Geek:
    def __init__(self, age = 0):
         self._age = age
    def get_age(self):
        return self._age
    def set_age(self, x):
        self._age = x
```

4. The error you get is returning you Supplier_105.supplier_name is not defined because you define your class object after your print. Since it is not instantiate as a class object yet he is looking in your dictionary also named Supplier_105. I would suggest giving your class object and your dictionary different name to avoid the confusion all together.

Good luck and remember Rome didn't build itself in 1 day. Programmation can be very hard when you start but It is very rewarding if you keep at it Good luck and if you have any question don't hesitate